# Is there any reason to use id= or name= on AngularJS directives?

Tags: angularjs

I have just noticed that I am coding stuff like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="userName" id="userName" name="userName" />
```

And it occurs to me that I have access to the data though `ng-data`. I will never use `getElementById()` or `getElementsByName()`.

Are the`id=` and `name=`just cluttering my HTML, or might I ever need them?

---

[Update] might they be of some use for automated testing?

Comment: If you ever need them, add them when you need them.

Comment: `name` might be useful for accessibility and automation. For example for a password manager.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the name attribute in input tags is used for form validation in the HTML scope. The errors for each element would be available in the form of: `myFormName.MyElementName.$error`.

For example, if your input tag has the 'required' attribute, the error flag would be accessible with `myForm.myElement.$error.required`

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615071/angularjs-form-validation-directive-setvalidity-on-element) is an example that requires the name attribute (validate some field in a directive).

Comment: And id can be useful for animation, jquery, etc. But no reason to include it if not used.